# Double Buffer presenting memory leaks [ANSI C]

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, pthreads

I am doing a library to implement a double buffer, the basic idea is there I will have to buffers, one will be written and the other read and they swap every time the write buffer gets full.
I am having memory leaks all the time when I am swapping the buffers and getting this from valgrind:

```
==4778== Thread 2:
==4778== Invalid read of size 1
==4778==    at 0x804A302: swapBuffer (doubleBuffer.c:85)
==4778==    by 0x804A1FA: setDoubleBuffer (doubleBuffer.c:39)
==4778==    by 0x804935C: TempControl (t2.c:167)
==4778==    by 0x4062F6F: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==4778==    by 0x4163BED: clone (clone.S:129)
==4778==  Address 0x4228098 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4,000 alloc'd
==4778==    at 0x402C109: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==4778==    by 0x804A0FF: build_double_buffer (doubleBuffer.c:14)
==4778==    by 0x8048E49: init (t2.c:56)
==4778==    by 0x804988A: main (t2.c:299)
==4778== 
==4778== Invalid read of size 1
==4778==    at 0x804A2E8: swapBuffer (doubleBuffer.c:86)
==4778==    by 0x804A1FA: setDoubleBuffer (doubleBuffer.c:39)
==4778==    by 0x804935C: TempControl (t2.c:167)
==4778==    by 0x4062F6F: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==4778==    by 0x4163BED: clone (clone.S:129)
==4778==  Address 0x4228098 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4,000 alloc'd
==4778==    at 0x402C109: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==4778==    by 0x804A0FF: build_double_buffer (doubleBuffer.c:14)
==4778==    by 0x8048E49: init (t2.c:56)
==4778==    by 0x804988A: main (t2.c:299)
==4778== 
==4778== Invalid write of size 1
==4778==    at 0x804A2EB: swapBuffer (doubleBuffer.c:86)
==4778==    by 0x804A1FA: setDoubleBuffer (doubleBuffer.c:39)
==4778==    by 0x804935C: TempControl (t2.c:167)
==4778==    by 0x4062F6F: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==4778==    by 0x4163BED: clone (clone.S:129)
==4778==  Address 0x4229068 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4,000 alloc'd
==4778==    at 0x402C109: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==4778==    by 0x804A11A: build_double_buffer (doubleBuffer.c:15)
==4778==    by 0x8048E49: init (t2.c:56)
==4778==    by 0x804988A: main (t2.c:299)
```

I've been trying to make it work, but I can't see where I am doing the memory leak not how to fix it.
The code is below:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include"data_structures.h"

#define BUFFER_SIZE 4000    

typedef enum {firstBuf, secondBuf} currentBuf;

typedef struct {
    char *buffer1;
    char *buffer2;
    currentBuf current;
    int index;
} double_buffer;


pthread_cond_t buffer_cheio = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t buffer_vazio = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
double_buffer *build_double_buffer(){
    double_buffer *db = (double_buffer *)malloc(sizeof(double_buffer));
    db->buffer1 = (char *)calloc(BUFFER_SIZE, sizeof(char));
    db->buffer2 = (char *)calloc(BUFFER_SIZE, sizeof(char));
    db->buffer1[0] = '\0';
    db->buffer2[0] = '\0';
    db->index = 0;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    db->current = firstBuf;
    return db;
}

void setDoubleBuffer(double_buffer *db, char *info){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    int len = strlen(info)+1;
    if(db->index + len > BUFFER_SIZE){
        switch(db->current){
            case firstBuf:
                while(db->buffer2[0] != '\0'){
                    pthread_cond_wait(&buffer_vazio, &mutex);
                }
                break;
            case secondBuf:
                while(db->buffer1[0] != '\0'){
                    pthread_cond_wait(&buffer_vazio, &mutex);
                }
        }
        swapBuffer(db);
    }
    if(db->current == firstBuf){
        if(!(db->index + len > BUFFER_SIZE)){
            strcat(db->buffer1, info);
        }else{
            printf("erro");
        }
    }else{
        if(!(db->index + len > BUFFER_SIZE)){
            strcat(db->buffer2, info);
        }else{
            printf("erro");
        }
    }
        db->index += len;
        pthread_cond_signal(&buffer_cheio);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void swapBuffer(double_buffer *db){
    int i;
    char *buf1;
    char *buf2;
    if(db->current == firstBuf) {
        buf1 = db->buffer1;
        buf2 = db->buffer2;
    } else {
        buf2 = db->buffer1;
        buf1 = db->buffer2;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE -1 || buf1[i] == '\0'; i++){ //line 85
        buf2[i] = buf1[i]; //line 86
    }
    buf1[0] ='\0';
    db->index = 0;
    if(db->current == firstBuf){
        db->current = secondBuf;
    }else{
        db->current = firstBuf;
    }
}

void get_buffer(char *receiveBuffer, double_buffer *db){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    int i;
    while(db->buffer1[0] == '\0' || db->buffer2[0] == '\0'){
        pthread_cond_wait(&buffer_cheio, &mutex);
    }
    if(db->current == firstBuf){
        for(i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE || db->buffer2[i] == '\0'; i++){
            receiveBuffer[i] = db->buffer2[i];
        }
        db->buffer2[0] = '\0';
    }else{
        for(i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE || db->buffer1[i] == '\0'; i++){
            receiveBuffer[i] = db->buffer1[i];
        }
        db->buffer1[0] = '\0';
    }
    pthread_cond_signal(&buffer_vazio);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

the code that calls this is:

```
//main thread before creating the threads
log_buffer = build_double_buffer();
//temparature thread
while(1){
    char *log_string = NULL;
    log_string = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

    //code that calculates T

    sprintf(log_string, "Temperura: %f\n", T);
    setDoubleBuffer(log_buffer, log_string);
}
```

Comment: It is not a memory leak, it tells you that you are reading past the end of the buffer.  That for(;;) loop is borken, it requires && instead of ||.

Comment: If I used `&&` I would read everything until the end of the buffer, but sometimes my buffer may not be totally full, because `setDoubleBuffer` may receive an arg info that doesn't fit in the current buffer, so it swaps.

Comment: Just reason it out in words, you continue to loop while you have not reached the end of the buffer AND the byte isn't zero.  That's not what you wrote.

Comment: You are quite right, thank you.